# Beginner: CSS and HTML working in Atom but not in GitHub

Tags: html, css, github-pages

Total beginner here looking for plain English answers :) 
I managed to successfully link my HTML and CSS sheets when using Atom and viewing the files in my browser, but now I'm trying to get this into my GitHub pages website and I can't make it work at all!

Here's the HTML: https://github.com/isbonnici/isabellabonnici.github.io/blob/master/index.html
Here's the CSS: https://github.com/isbonnici/isabellabonnici.github.io/blob/master/CAstylesheet.css

What am I doing wrong? Really would appreciate the help here.

Comment: The reason you are receiving a 404 error on your website is because your github directory is called "isabellabonnici" when your github username is "isbonnici". In order for pages to work your directory must be "isbonnici.github.io" as it must match your username.

Comment: I changed it to isbonnici -- still not working :( any ideas? Amit mentioned something about a master branch and publishing as personal pages

Comment: https://isbonnici.github.io/ works from my location.

Answer (score 1):

There is no css folder in your github account. Remove **css/** from the css path. It should start working. Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/CAstylesheet.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CAstylesheet.css">
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, create a css folder and move CAstylesheet.css into it.

Comment: I changed it to what you said Amit and it doesn't appear to be working https://isbonnici.github.io (404 not found). Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place? Should a create a folder like Toby mentioned and try that? No idea how to do that either but will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: This is a publishing issue now. You have now put your source code in master branch. But it is not published to be used as your personal pages.